# Reduce voltage/amperage from adapter to fit another device

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, current-source, adapter

Complete newbie here.

So I got this old gaming console with the original adapter, which outputs 8.2V / 850mA. The cable connection with the body of the adapter is somewhat loose, though, so if you twist it in this particular way, no less, no more, and manage not to move it, the console stays powered up and it's usable.

I'd like to build my own adapter for the console using another, newer adapter which outputs 9V and 1A. The cable has two inner cables with which could (presumably?) be connected to a circuit that corrects these values so that they match the console requirements. Is this even possible? What would such a circuit look like?

I'm in Europe, in case this matters at all.

Comment: I really feel like your best bet is to just get one someone else has made; unless this game console is something extremely uncommon, there will be replacement parts available on the internet from companies that specialize in that sort of thing.

Comment: If you told us exactly which gaming console it is, someone might know if it is safe to run it directly from a 9 V adapter. Is the old adapter screwed together such that you could open it up to replace the socket?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to open the console and get your hands dirty, you are looking for something called voltage regulator near the DC socket on board.

But in your case, I would say the 9V-1A adapter would work fine.(Reason being the circuits are generally designed to regulate any offset voltages.)

Answer (score 1):

The circuit you are looking for is called "linear voltage regulator". Internally a regulator is like automatically adjustable resistor: it adjusts it's resistance so that the voltage between output and reference (often ground) point gets a pre-determined value. With a quick search, I couldn't find one with 8.2 V output voltage, but you can take for example 5 V regulator and create your own value with a voltage divider (two resistors) between output, reference leg, and ground. For example datasheet, http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2096735.pdf

You don't need to worry about the current, for your console the current is just the maximum current it can take. For the power supply, the voltage is the maximum current it can give. The console won't draw more current than it needs. You need to pick a regulator where the maximum output current AND maximum power dissipation is sufficiently high. As @Hearth commented below, you will need a regulator with a sufficiently low voltage drop. There are often denoted with the acronym "LDO", but you must check the dropout voltage from the datasheet.

It's very probable, that the console works just fine with no voltage regulator in between.

Comment: Your suggestion of an LM78xx will not work, as linear regulators _cannot_ output a voltage greater than \$V_{in} - V_{do}\$, and \$V_{do}\$ for the 78xx series is something like 1.5V or even 2V. The LM317 adjustable regulator has this problem as well. You need something called a "Low-dropout" or LDO linear regulator for this job.

Comment: @Hearth: For a while, people were calling *any* linear regulator an "LDO".  That usage was even creeping into datasheets.  So -- look at the datasheet's dropout voltage spec.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.

Comment: It's also not considered good practice to take a fixed-voltage one and try to adjust its voltage, though it'd probably work for most purposes. I'd just use an adjustable one.

Answer (score 1):

If the game is more than about 15 years old, or if the adapter is significantly bigger and bulkier than a cell phone charger (i.e. if it's two inches on a side or more) then the adapter is probably just a transformer and an unregulated DC supply.

This means that the game will have its own voltage regulation, and as @user24368 suggests, you can just use a 9V regulated adapter and it'll be close enough.  The regulator inside your game will run a bit hot, but hopefully not *too* hot.

You could also run a 9V adapter and put a single power diode or a resistor in series with one of the leads (the '+' lead is traditional, but not necessary).  A 1-ohm resistor would drop your (presumably regulated) 9V down to 8.2V or so at 820mA.

However, any series element (even a linear regulator) you use would get warm, because it has to burn up power to drop the voltage.  Given that you'd probably want to make a "wart" on the cable, I'd use a 5W, 1\$\Omega\$ resistor in line with one of the leads, and I'd cover it with heat shrink tubing.  Then I'd check to make sure that it wasn't getting *too* hot -- and if you ever had a fire start behind the game, your homeowners or renters insurance company would use the modified cord as an excuse to call it your fault.

Comment: +1 for considering the thermals.